# Why can't I access a private field even though I have auto-implemented properties { get; set; }?

Tags: c#

I tried to search for this question on the website however could not find an answer. I checked the MSDN document about auto-implemented properties and the examples provided are only `public` fields in classes. My example class:

```
public class Area
{
    private bool enabled { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I try to access the enabled field of this class, from another class, I get an error, "Area.enabled is inaccessible due to its protection level". I don't understand why it is not accessible as auto-implemented properties are written and even though my field is private, I have `get` and `set`?

Comment: "Whenever I try to access the enabled field of this class, from another class" - what do you think `private` *means* if you think you can access such members from other classes?

Comment: You can't access the property itself, as you declared it as `private`.

Comment: Your property is `private` itself, have a look at [private keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private)

Comment: first of all, you need to understand what is private means?

Comment: `get` and `set` have no relationship with property visibility.

Comment: Coming from C++ and Java background, I think I'm confusing get/set methods with auto-implemented properties.

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is a private automatically implemented property (not a field).

Essentially it is similar to:

```cs
private bool _enabled; // the field
private bool Enabled // the property declaration
{
    get { return _enabled; } // the property getter
    set { _enabled = value; } // the property setter
}
```

(except the field name is not `_enabled`, but: something unpronounceable)

The *field* in an automatically implemented property is always `private`; here the *property* is **also** `private`. Having `private` properties is perfectly common. So: indeed, it will be inaccessible outside of `Area`.

If that wasn't intended: use a more permissive accessibility; `protected`, `internal`,  `public` etc.

Comment: so whats the difference between declaring the field private and writing getter and setter methods or using, for instance, `internal` access modifier?

Comment: @cptalpdeniz It seems you are confusing the concept of access modifiers with the concept of fields and properites. Fields are simple members of a type. Properties are members that have getters and setters, which are member methods that can do whatever they want. If it's an auto-property, the getter and setter are implemented by the compiler to return or set a field with a compiler-generated name you cannot see. On the other hand, all of these members can have _access modifiers_ that declare who can access these members.